# соответствие произвольной капчи (capture) в конкрентой именированой групе

Tags: .net, регулярные-выражения

Есть такое регулярное выражение `^(?<num>\d){4}\<num>$`.
Его подстрока `\<num>` интерпретируетися как последняя каптча (capture) именированой групе *num*. Как сделать чтобы подстрока `\<num>` интерпретировалась как произвольная (одна из набора) каптча (capture) конкретной именированой групе?
Например, если заданному регулярному выражению подать на вход строку `"12344"`, то даная строка исполняет требования заданного регулярноого выражения. Эти строки - нет:

```
"12341"
"12342"
"12343"
```

рабочая технология - .net.

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите, чтобы совпадение было найдено во всех 4 строках? Всегда ли строка состоит из 5 цифр или это пример?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Да. Это пример.

Comment: Кажется, никак.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну мне только вот такое в голову приходит:

```
^(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\1|\2|\3|\4)$
```

Comment: Цифр может быть сколько угодно, и, как я понял, в группе захвата могут быть не только цифровой, а любой шаблон (вообще, даже несколько, необязательно `\d`).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, если максимальное количество цифр ограничено, то у необязательных надо поставить знаки вопроса, а перед последним куском `(?=.)(\1|\2)$`. В вопросе регулярка только для цифр и их всегда 5: `^(?<num>\d){4}\<num>$`, моя ей соответствует. В большинстве случаев подход из ответа использовать можно.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, хотя да, придумал вариант лучше.

Comment: Этот подход все равно не сработате в `TEXT[a-z]+-(\d{3}-\d{5})+(?????)END`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, в другой ответ смотри - там получится.

Comment: Да, другой вариант может сработать.

Answer (score 0):

От 4 до 6 цифр, причём последняя цифра встречается среди предыдущих:

```
^(?=\d{4,6}$)\d*(\d)\d*\1$
```